# Unix script - Comparing number of filename date with my single input date

Tags: bash

I am new to Unix scripting, I am trying to create Unix script since one week but I couldn't. Please help me in this.

I have a number of different files more than 100 (all the filenames are different) which the filename contains the date string(ex: 20171101)in the directory. I want compare these filename dates with my input date (today - 10days =20171114),with the files in the directories only using filename string date if it is less than with my input date then I have to delete the file. could anyone please help on this. Thanks

My script:

```
ten_days_ago=$(date -d "10 days ago" +%Y%m%d)

cd "$destination_dir" ;     
ls *.* | awk -F '-' '{print $2}'     
ls *.* | awk -F '-' '{print $2}' > removal.txt

while read filedate     
do    
if [ "$filedate" -lt "$ten_days_ago" ] ; then     
    cd "$destination_dir" ;    
    rm *-"$filedate"*    
    echo "deletion done"
fi

done <removal.txt
```

this script is working fine. but I need to send a email as well - if the deletion has been done then -one pass email else fail email.
but here within while loop if I am writing the emails then that will iterate

Comment: Post some code you have, even if it is incomplete.  We can build on it.

Comment: No, post code in your question.  Putting it in a comment makes a mess.

Comment: Writing the same command sequence twice is never a good idea.  To display the output from a command and save it to a file at the same time, use `tee`. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Answer (score 0):

You're probably trying to pipe to `mail` from the middle of your loop. (Your question should really show this code, otherwise we can't say what's wrong.)  A common technique is to redirect the loop's output to a file, and then send that.  (Using a temporary file is slightly ugly, but avoids sending an empty message when there is no output from the loop.)

Just loop over the files and decide which to remove.

```
#!/bin/bash

t=$(mktemp -t tendays.XXXXXXXX) || exit
# Remove temp file if interrupted, or when done
trap 'rm -f "$t"' EXIT HUP INT TERM

ten_days_ago=$(date -d "10 days ago" +%Y%m%d)
for file in *-[1-9]*[1-9]-*; do
    date=${file#*-}  # strip prefix up through first dash
    date=${date%-*}  # strip from last dash from the previous result
    if [ "$date" -lt "$ten_days_ago" ]; then
        rm -v "$file"
    fi
done >"$t" 2>&1

test -s "$t" || exit  # Quit if empty

mail -s "Removed files" recipient@example.net <"$t"
```

I removed the (repeated!) `cd` so this can be run in any directory -- just switch to the directory you want before running the script.  This also makes it easier to test in a directory with a set of temporary files.

Collecting the script's standard error also means the mail message will contain any error messages if `rm` fails for some reason or you have other exceptions.

By the by [you should basically never use `ls` in scripts.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: This will misbehave if some file names have more than two dashes.  Your question is unclear on this point.

Comment: It's not working. My requirement is just to compare the two dates (one date lies in the filename and the other date is constant date I.e my input date) if difference between two dates is 10 then I need to remove such files in the folder.

Comment: That's already stated in the question. Can you post a `bash -x` transcript of a run which isn't doing what you expect, perhaps on https://pastebin.com/?

Comment: I missed your mail requirement. This is now updated to address that, too.